# Корректное восстановление приложения из закладок

Tags: android, activity, context

Как известно, при сворачивании, начиная с Android 5, приложение уходит в закладки. При этом отрабатывает стандартная цепочка событий `onPause->onStop->onDestroy`.

При восстановлении приложения из закладок:

1. Отличается ли цепочка цепочка событий от стандартной (`onCreate->onStart->onResume`)?
2. Как корректно восстановить состояние `Activity` (просто бывали случаи, когда во фрагментах `Context` был `null`)?

Comment: Что значит `Context был null`? Локальная переменная или как вы получаете ссылку на контекст?

Comment: Из моих наблюдений, то цепочка ничем не отличается только от ситуации когда у вас была убита активность системой или нет.

Comment: Ну во фрагментах Context=null, только при условии что не было создано/ещё создано Активити, у вас есть все средства для этой проверки. Если я ошибаюсь, поправьте меня

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Изучите внимательно жизненный цикл активити. Например [тут](https://metanit.com/java/android/2.1.php). Вы можете попасть в любой из трех методов, в зависимости от ситуации. Именно при восстановлении после перехода к другому приложению гарантированно отработает onStart. Если приложение при этом было вычищено из памяти, то и в onCreate попадете. Если не было вычищено, но будучи в другом приложении вы сменили ориентацию экрана и вернулись к своему, то так же отработает onCreate

2) где именно вы получили null в контексте у фрагмента? Из доступных для переопределения методов фрагмента самым первым отрабатывает onAttach, и он уже получает контекст в параметрах. Единственный вариант, который могу придумать: вы не прикрепляете фрагмент к активити при ее восстановлении и обращаетесь к вами созданному методу фрагмента, вызывающему `getContex()`. Так, конечно, делать нельзя. 
Для более обстоятельного ответа приведите код своего фрагмента, который выбрасывает нул.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ваши советы помогли!